# boot2docker bash command line is very slow

Tags: windows, bash, docker, boot2docker

Followed a few tutorials online regarding installing boot2docker ISO release v1.3.0 on a windows 7 enterprise machine. The same steps work fine on a mac!!! We've a number of custom docker files that I want to link and manage for our development environment. However, when I run the boot2docker from the desktop it can take either 3 seconds or a minute to load, when it does the command line can lag about 20-30 seconds behind what the user is typing.

I've tried reinstalling, cleaning anything from my PATH, increased the memory, played with the different boot2docker init settings but I'm unable to resolve the issue with the command line lag!

Has anybody experienced this issue?

Thanks.

J

Comment: Yes Im using windows! Trying to make our dev environment containers common across different OS's. I reverted to using putty instead which seems to work as expected. Would be nice not to have to do this extra task.

Comment: Did you delete all the iso and dot files and folders associated with boot2docker and virtualbox?

Comment: Ya, did a fresh install, removed any dot files/folders both from the users directory and the program files.

Comment: I see, I've also found that downgrading to an earlier version of `VirtualBox` solves various problems.

Comment: someone has come up with the solution in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344406/why-is-bash-so-painfully-slow-in-boot2docker-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Havent managed to find a solution. Removed all dot files, fresh install...same problem. However, there was once it started up where there was no lag on the command line. Work around is to use SSH using the default user/pass, at least I can progress with.

Thanks for your help.

J

Answer (score 0):

It may be the same problem: `boot2docker ssh` was dramatically slow after installing Docker for Windows. I've found a solution replacing the default ssh client.

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30344973/1231681