# Why is bash so painfully slow in boot2docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, boot2docker

I have installed boot2docker on Windows 7 and I have noticed that it is incredibly slow. I have tried on several machines with the same result - it takes a while to load and the worst part is the lag between typing and the characters actually appearing on screen is horrible - around 20-30 seconds! This makes boot2docker virtually impossible to use on windows.

I wonder if someone has come accross this problem and can see any solution?

Comment: Duplicate (without answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648578/boot2docker-bash-command-line-is-very-slow?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem comes from the SSH client when running `boot2docker ssh`. This SSH client is searched on the `%PATH%` and on my system, by default, it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`. Like you reported, it is dramatically slow.

By the way, if you open a command-line and run directly `ssh <boot2docker IP address>` to connect to the boot2docker VM, it is also very slow whereas using shell inside the Boot2docker VM itself is fine.

I don't know yet why this SSH client is slow BUT I've replaced it successfully by installing Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/) and overloading `%PATH%`:

```
C:\> set PATH=C:\PrgFiles\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%
C:\> boot2docker ssh`
```

No more slowness.